# Many to many comparison in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server the column contains some center codes in comma separated formats like 
`0000700118,0000700120,0000700123,0000700163`.

[image: comma separated column screen]

and the values compared by same value but the  center code separation order is different LIKE `0000700123,0000700118,0000700120,0000700163`.

How to compare the many to many values in SQL Server. Help me anyone to resolve the issue.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a string!

Comment: You need to fix your design; don't store delimited values and then you don't have a problem.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? What is your expected outpu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find rows which have the same values in CostElementName (with/without the same ordering):

```
declare @t table
(
    id int identity,
    CostElementGroup varchar(10),
    CostElementName varchar(max)
);

insert into @t
(
    CostElementGroup, CostElementName
)
values ('A', '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'), ('A', '5, 4, 3, 2, 1'),
('A', '3, 4, 5'), ('A', '3, 5, 4'),
('A', '1, 2, 3'), ('A', '1, 2');

select *
from @t as a
join @t as b on a.CostElementGroup = b.CostElementGroup and a.id <> b.id
where 
--same number of elements in the comma delimited string...
len(a.CostElementName) - len(replace(a.CostElementName, ',', '')) = len(b.CostElementName) - len(replace(b.CostElementName, ',', ''))
and not exists --...without any diff
(
    select ltrim(x.value)
    from string_split(a.CostElementName, ',') as x
    except
    select ltrim(y.value)
    from string_split(b.CostElementName, ',') as y
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have all the values in a single string. Try and parse the data before introducing it in the table so that you can add each element on a new line in the table as a varchar. Afterwards, it's easier to compare the entire column with a value.